# Check if Type instance equals generic type

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I need to implement a Java interface that has a method similar to this:

```
boolean canWrite(Type t);
```

In my case it should return `true` if the type is `List<URI>`.

I though of doing something like `return t.equals(URI_LIST_TYPE)`, but I don't know how to get an instance of [Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) that represents `List<URI>`.

Is there a pretty way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You need a *type token*, for example [the one in Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html) that is used like this

```
new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}
```

This works because (anonymous) subclasses retain the information about the type parameters at runtime, and are then inspectable by reflection libraries.

<sub>As a side node, when designing an API that deals with reflection,  don't use `Class<E>` as an input parameter if parameterized types can come into play</sub>

Comment: I don't use Guava and would rather not include it just for this.

Answer (score 0):

Since I already use **Spring** I found [ParameterizedTypeReference class](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ParameterizedTypeReference.html) to be useful. (I guess it is similar to Guava's `TypeToken`.) In my case:

```java
URI_LIST_TYPE = (new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<URI>>() {}).getType();
```

There is also the possibility to compare as string:

```
t.toString().equals("java.util.List<java.net.URI>")
```

Or the more defined behaviour with **Java 8**:

```
t.getTypeName().equals("java.util.List<java.net.URI>")
```